# How to insert a table in RichTextBox as one entity?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'm making a simple document editor in `C# Windows Form  Application`. I have inserted a table to my `RichTextBox` by using the below code.

```
public void richTextBox1_InsertTable(int row, int column)
{
    StringBuilder tableRTF = new StringBuilder();

    tableRTF.Append(@"\trowd");
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
            tableRTF.Append(@"\cellx" +  (j + 1) * 1000);
        tableRTF.Append(@"\intbl \cell \row");
    };
    tableRTF.Append(@"\pard");
    richTextBox1.Rtf = richTextBox1.Rtf.Trim().TrimEnd('}') + tableRTF.ToString();
}
```

But, In this way, I can't select a table by clicking. And if I set EnableAutoDragDrop property to true, A bug occured like below image.

[Before Dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DidVl.png)

[After Dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L93mp.png)

So, I want to insert a table as one entity like inserted image. Is there any good way to solve this problem??

Comment: I'm afraid that you can not do it. The support of RTF in build in `RichTextBox` is bad. You can not use it as a serious editor. I tried a while ago implement simple functions beyond RTF 1.5 specification and none of the tested functions worked.

Comment: Oh.... thank you for giving information...